# How do I get FreeSWITCH to workout the sofia profile for me from Originate

Tags: freeswitch

I have some code using the FreeSWITCH api over sockets. I am originating calls.

When I use my SIP phone to test things I can simply enter a number and mod_dialplan_xml kicks in on FreeSWITCH to work out the necessary sofia profiles.

When I want to originate a call in code it seems to me that I need to know which sofia profile to use.

e.g.

for an external call

originate "sofia/gateway/provider/012345678"

for an internal call

originate "sofia/internal/1000%"

What I would like to do is have my code ask FreeSWITCH what the correct sofia profile is, or provide a profile that indicates to FreeSWITCH to figure it out for me.

I've looked at the docs and the forums and scoured Google but I can't find an answer, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running 'sofia status gateway' etc and parse out to see which gateways are available